# Please anyone explain what is the difference between English and The English language?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

Between the three sentences

1. **English** opens the the window upon the world's knowledge.
2. **English language** opens the the window upon the world's knowledge.
3. **The English language** opens the the window upon the world's knowledge.

I think first one is more appropriate but can the remaining two sentences imply same meaning?

If not what is their meaning?

Are they grammatically correct? Please explain to me.

Comment: Also, **The English** can mean "the people of England"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One meaning of the word *English* is *the English language.* (See [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/english)). So Sentences 1 and 3 mean the same thing and they are both appropriate.

Sentence 2 is not good because of the lack of a determiner before *English language*. When it is used as a noun, *English language* needs an article (or some kind of other [determiner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determiner), such as a number: *One English language is all the world really needs*). Most of the time the article will be *the* because *English language*, like *Engish* by itself, is a proper noun.

However, sometimes proper nouns can be used with the indefinite article: *American English is an English language that I don't like. I prefer New Zealand English. Now that's an English language I can get excited about.*